# Four distinct integers a,b,c,d are in A.P. If $a^2+b^2+c^2=d$, then find$ a+b+c+d$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Four distinct integers a,b,c,d are in arithmetic progression. If $a^2+b^2+c^2=d$, then find $a+b+c+d$.

My attempt:-
[image]

Comment: What is *A.P.*?

Comment: Arithmetic Progression

Comment: Should it be $d^2$ instead of $d$

Comment: If so, Let $a,b,c,d$  be $A\pm3D, A\pm D$ where $D\ge0$

$$(A+3D)^2=(A-D)^2+(A+D)^2+(A-3D)^2$$

$$A^2-6AD+D^2=0\implies\dfrac AD=3\pm2\sqrt2$$

Now $a+b+c+d=4A$

Comment: I wondered that myself but the book says it is d not $d^2$

Comment: @AbhishekMhatre Books, whilst usually more reliable than people, are quite often mistaken!

Comment: It is correct the way it is in the book. The integer solutions are: $A=x=0$ and $A=-1$, $x=1$

Comment: See my answer for how these two solutions are derived.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you did, let $a=A-x,b=A$. 
Then, we have
$$2x^2\color{red}{-}2x+3A^2-A=0,$$
i.e.
$$x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{-6A^2+2A+1}}{2}$$
Since $x$ has to be an integer, let $-6A^2+2A+1=m^2$ to have 
$$6m^2+\left(6A-1\right)^2=7$$

So, $7-6m^2\ge 0\implies m=0,\pm 1$ giving $(m,A)=(\pm 1,0)$.

Since $a,b,c,d$ are distinct,
$$a+b+c+d=4A+2x=0+2=\color{red}{2}$$
where $(a,b,c,d)=(-1,0,1,2)$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a=A-X$, $b=A$, $c=A+X$, $d=A+2X$, with $A,X$ integers. Then $a^2+b^2+c^2=d$ becomes:

$3A^2+2X^2=A+2X$

$3A^2-A+2X^2-2X=0$

Multiply by 2:

$6A^2-2A+4X^2-4X=0$

$5A^2+(A-1)^2+(2X-1)^2=2$

Since $5A^2$ is divisible by $5$, we can only have $A=0$. Otherwise the sum of the squares exceeds $2$

Now $2X-1=\pm 1$ which gives $X=0$ or $X=2$

So we have either:

$a=b=c=d=0$, so $a+b+c+d=0$

or

$a=-1$, $b=0$, $c=1$, $d=2$, so $a+b+c+d=2$